# Error messages are not printing in eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

I am making a cross platform application that can be run as a java application and an android application. I have this bit of code that leads to a null pointer exception (I know it does because I put it there in purpose). The problem is that there is no error output to the console (with the offending line number and so forth) when I run the application as a java application. If I run the same application as an android application, then I see the error on Logcat. The strange thing is that the console used to display errors but has since stopped. Is there a way to enable a fatal error message to appear on the console?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change the workspace and create a new workspace then try to import the same project and run it. Hope this will help you!